# Famous games written in Python

Tags: python

I've seen a couple of these, namely [Java](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3789/famous-games-written-in-java) and [C#/XNA](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1667/famous-games-written-in-net-and-xna)...and I've recently been picking up Python. Which kind of made me think.

What (famous) games have been written in Python, with Pygame/Pyglet/Pyopengl?

Comment: CW is now a mod-only feature. Converted. Also consider flagging your post with that reason if you want us to get to it faster.

Comment: Huh... I thought he was just overlooking the box, but you're right, @Tetrad, wiki is now mod-only. Seems strange, why wouldn't they allow users to apply it themselves?

Comment: [Missing in Action: the Wiki button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action). Apparently it was causing *confusion and pain* to users - next to go will be the *Search* button...

Comment: Some games use Python for scripting. I heard Unreal is going to use Python, not sure if it is true, though.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[**Eve Online**](http://www.eveonline.com/) is probably the biggest, and uses [Stackless Python](http://www.stackless.com/), a lightweight, microthreaded version of Python. And Civilization IV had a Python interpreter built-in, but I'm not sure if that was for scripting only, or how much of the game was written in it.

Also, Disney's [Pirates of the Caribbean](http://www.panda3d.org/showss.php?shot=ssg-pirates/pirates01) was written using the [Panda3d](http://www.panda3d.org/) game engine (which allows both Python and C++ scripting, but from googling it - Disney used Python). The *engine* is in C++, but then again, the Python *interpreter* itself also uses a lot of C code. :)

For a long list of games:

- [Python Games](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGames)

which also covers a lot of well-known games, like [Mount and Blade](http://www.taleworlds.com/).

Comment: The graphics engine for Eve is custom and written in C/C++, so by these requirements it wouldn't be "in Python".

Comment: @coderanger, true - but the condition (*famous game* && *pure Python*) == **null** - so I dropped the *pure* condition, whereas you dropped the *famous* condition. :) (Unless Galcon is famous, but I suspect Eve Online is moreso).

Comment: Actually only the client is in C++.

Comment: @RadomirDopieralski Do you have a reference for that?  I'd like to know for sure since you all disagree.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The original version of [Galcon](http://www.galcon.com/) was in pure Python, though it has long since been ported to other languages (at last count there were Obj-C, Flash, and C++ versions). It does still use Python for AI via the TinyPy library, but I suppose that is "just scripting".

As a general comment, Python isn't really well suited for making a blazingly fast graphics engine. You get far more control writing the core, performance-sensitive code in C or C++ and then writing the complex game logic in Python. Python excels at the more logic related areas since its expressiveness is a productivity win over C and the drop in performance isn't an issue. This is why everyone (CCP, Panda3D, Unity, Civ4, etc) all work like this. The real question is does this count as being "in Python"? For example, in Eve everything related to the actual game (more or less) is in Python, the C++ part is just a generic game engine that handles pushing pixels and audio.

Answer (score 9):

[Frets on Fire](http://fretsonfire.sourceforge.net/) (in addition to Galcon, which is not native Python anymore) is the only "native Python" game I can think of that achieved some degree of lasting fame.

Answer (score 4):

Also, Battlefield Heroes, the cartoony version of battlefield (Handles most of the game logic)

And, BattleField 2 and 2142 (For logic and server controls)

http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGames

Comment: Source? For why should DICE write a new game/engine in Python when they have good ones in C++ already?

Comment: A link is good.

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGames It says on the page that Battlefield Heroes uses Python

Comment: Seriously why do I get downvoted for NO REASON!

Comment: I downvoted you because you didn't provide any source or details.  Now that you added that, I removed it.

Comment: Well maybe if you looked at the same link at the top, you wouldn't of given me downvotes like you usually do!

Comment: @PeterØlsted It's well known that 2142 and others use Python, a simple Google would have told you that.

Answer (score 2):

Disney's "Toontown" and "Pirates of the Carribean Online" use the Panda3D engine with Python scripting.

http://toontown.go.com/
http://piratesonline.go.com/welcome

http://panda3d.org/