# python for game development

Tags: python, pygame

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Famous games written in Python](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5035/famous-games-written-in-python)

Is python any good for game development? Can I have some examples of great indie python games.

So I can have an idea what it's capable of?

I'm looking for games which are on a realistic scale for one person.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGames

The go-to resource for python games.