# Does C# have a future in games development?

Tags: c#, software-engineering, game-industry, .net

I recently learned that the MMO Minecraft is powered by Java from a recent interview on CVG.co.uk on a possible collaboration between two former and now competing colleagues. In the interview he bluntly said that the founder of Minecraft is a Java coder and he is a C or C++ coder so they are incompatible with each other. So collaborating on future projects will be difficult.

This got me thinking, If Java could do that? What does the future hold for MS very popular C# language and .Net platform as far as games or mainstream games development is concerned?

Comment: Yes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA

Comment: It's all about the performances you need, Minecraft is ok in a managed language, but for high end graphics games, C or C++ or other natives languages are prefered

Comment: Minecraft is not really an MMO.

Comment: @Guillaume86: Jittered code can currently outperform native code, and Jits are getting better all the time. Also, managed languages produce far more robust programs. So in the end C++ loses it's performance advantage, and is significantly harder to write robust programs in (which means longer development times and more costs)

Comment: A JIT can beat poorly written native code, not tightly optimized and tuned inner loops. Granted even with C# you have the option of writing those sensitive segments in C/C++ if you really want.

Comment: Notch (The author of minecraft) also played a large part in Wyrm Online, which was written in C++ - he's not a "Java coder" so much as "a coder who knows java".

Comment: C# is faster than C++ by about 3 months.

Comment: Uh.. are you basically asking if unity has a future? =)

Comment: @coderanger Of course super optimised native code can beat jittered code. But doing those kind of optimisations is time consuming and costly. Where writing all your managed code is almost as fast, and a helluva lot easier/faster to develop. And if one of the companies out there started releasing games twice as fast as they currently do, with less bugs, I think gamers would be pretty happy about that - even if it took 5% more CPU load ;)

Comment: @Martin See my answer [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1667/famous-games-written-in-net-and-xna/1670#1670) to see why that doesn't really happen that often. I can also say from personal experience that a 5% decrease in RAM usage can save thousands (multiple concurrent server processes, less RAM means less hardware means less $$$). As a big Python supporter I would love to the CLR become a more viable option for AAA game development, but it sure as hell isn't there yet.

Comment: @coderanger: I know that currently not many large studios use managed languages, and I'm sure that's going to continue for a very long time. However more and more small scale companies are using managed languages, and I can't imagine that going away anytime soon either.

Comment: I'm sure its not ironic then that Minecraft is an incredible performance hog?

Answer (score 22):

You should check out [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA). A platform for building games for Windows, Xbox 360 and Windows Mobile 7. All in C# and .NET.

Answer (score 11):

I've been working in professional game development for over 5 years. Most of this time, I used C# almost exclusively.

C# and .NET stack in general is really great for server-side tech. I've worked on no less than 4 MMO games with server written in C#. Also, with Unity3D gaining popularity, many browser AND mobile games require C#. Don't forget XNA framework: it's not the engine of choice for AAA console titles, but there are many great games made with it, and many more currently in the making.

Overall, C# definitely has a future in game development.

Comment: it's an old question, but one thing bothers me. "server-side tech" - what exactly do you mean by that? A WindowsService running on some Windows Server using .NET Framework? I always thought that servers are made in c++ and running on unix os. I was just curious

Comment: Yep, exactly that. There are lots of servers running on Windows out there - including the ones that run this very site, AFAIK.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. Just to clarify - "running on Windows" as headless Windows Services or programs like WinForms (with built in config or something like that)?

Comment: Headless service is usually a better idea, but nothing's stopping you from just running a console application. Or even a GUI one, except there's no one on the server to use said GUI.

Answer (score 10):

As has been mentioned, [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) brings C# to multiple platforms. In that same area, you'll find [Tao](http://www.mono-project.com/Tao), a multiplatform library for Mono and .NET that allows access to Cg, DevIL, FreeGLUT, GLFW, GLU, ODE, OpenAl, OpenGL, PhysicsFS, SDL, and WGL. It's obviously not as robust when it comes to features as XNA (which provides fundamental engine components directly to the developer); but, it's plenty powerful.

So, cross platform beyond Microsoft controlled OS's and hardware is definitely possible. Just, not as many popular indie games have utilized this ability, yet.

As has also been mentioned, XNA coupled with C# allows independent developers to publish to the 360, PC, and Windows Phone 7.

Overall, C# is alive and well in game development as an engine/game language.

As a tools language, it's in use everywhere. I've built tools for EA, THQ, and now Arkadium all using C#.

Answer (score 5):

Not only does C# have a future in games development, it has a present -
Check out [Magicka](http://www.magickagame.com/), a game recently released (and selling well) that was developed using XNA.
Also take a look at the winning [Dream.Build.Play](http://www.dreambuildplay.com/Main/Winners.aspx) entries. C# is a viable way to make games (although right now I don't believe it's the right choice for *all* games).

As time goes by we'll see it becoming more popular in the computer gaming industry, however I don't expect a sudden shift to C# at any point.

Answer (score 4):

Java has always been a very versatile language and there's always been the ability for people to code games in it, from simple web based games (Java applets / GWT with the canvas plugin) to full 3D beasts (checkout [JMonkey](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/)). So I wouldn't say the fact Java can do that sort of thing is a C# killer, because most people know Java can do that already.

C# will still remain popular though since it inevitably ties in with Windows, Windows mobile and the Xbox much better than Java (which, really, is all game developers really care about targeting so the cross platform advantage that Java has is mostly lost.) It's also got XNA which has really taken off in terms of game development.

So yes, Java is a perfectly good platform for games development if anyone wishes to go down that route, but it's certainly no C# or .NET killer.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Unity 3D; C# (and JavaScript, and Boo) scripting in a high-performance 3D engine.

Add XNA to the mix and you're looking at a couple of great platforms for using C# for game development.

Comment: Unity also has a web player so you could play in the browser. The plugin doesn't have a huge market penetration like flash or java, but it's possible.

Comment: yay for unity!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, C# has a future, with the XNA framework. Most prefer C++ because of speed, but C# is not **that** slow anymore...

Comment: It's not slow at all. It's rarely worse than about 70% of C++ speed, and can even be faster sometimes!

Comment: CPU bound operations in C# are quite fast, it does some extra checking which vastly improves the safety of code at the cost of some minor performance hits but where it's much worse than C++ is in memory consumption and management. It's a heck of a lot easier and less leak prone in C# but the performance hits of the GC can be an absolute dog.

Comment: Beware when targeting the Xbox360 though. The XNA runtime there lacks the ability for some of the major optimizations and prevents you from shifting performance sensitive portions to unmanaged code.

Answer (score 1):

Also - [MonoDroid](http://www.softwareassociates.in/blog/net/monodroid/) may be an option for C#.

Answer (score 1):

What he did with Java in this instance was create an applet so that you could just log on to the site and play with a very common plugin, completely transparent to which operating system was being used. I imagine his thinking was that Java was quite transparent when used this way and it would make it easy for the quick iterative development / testing he was getting fans to do. I don't believe you can just do this with XNA because usually the tester has to have everything installed as well as the game and some general knowledge about how to compile and run this.

So I would say that there is no paradigm shift from this, it just suited what he needed at the time and obviously worked out well.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, lots of programming languages have a future in games development.  It is an often used false dilemma used in the computing press that there can be only one tool of type X and that everybody wants this to occur.

Nothing could be farther from the truth.

C# and Java have been used in games for a long time.  C and C++ have for even longer, and still are.  Lua is used as the scripting language for some incredibly popular games, with the engine written in C/C++.

So clearly, no programming language is blowing other programming languages out of the water as The Game Programming Language.  In fact, we see a tendency for leading games to be composed of a high performance compiled programming language for developing the engine(s) in. and then a higher level dynamic programming language for scripting how the UI and stuff behaves.

The key at the moment is performance.  If any of the programming languages/libraries used cause unpredictable/uncontrollable pauses in the application then in an action game, that will fall flat on its face. In a text-based adventure game, that might be okay however.