# Xna performance

Tags: xna, c#, performance

I'm thinking about starting to write a game and my primary concern is performance. I was thinking about writing it in xna (client), and then also writing the server in c#. Will this be fast enough for any game that requires twitch reactions (like a top down shooter).

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1667/what-are-some-famous-games-developed-with-net-and-or-xna, so: "yes"

Comment: This question is way too broad.  If you had a specific case where performance wasn't good and you wanted to ask on how to work around it, then it would be on topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  The XNA Framework is perfectly capable of building any type of game.  If I were you, I would worry more about building a game first, rather than how well it will run once built.

Comment: I'm just nervous that I'm going to spend a bunch of time on this and then find out that I can't optimize it enough (or it would take too much work to optimize) so I would have to throw it away. Thanks for the answer though! At the very least I just learn a lot so should be fun